# Unit test angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

So I am following along with the unit testing for a directive but I can't get it to compile...

**directive**

```
home.directive('myDirective', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            text: '@',
            href: '@'
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {            
            var text = '<span>Text: <a href="'+scope.href+'">'+scope.text+'</a><br />';
            text += 'HREF: '+scope.href+'</span>';
            var newElement = $compile(text)(scope);            
            elem.replaceWith(newElement);
        }
    };
})
```

**Test**

```
describe( 'Test home controller', function() {
    beforeEach( module( 'home' ) );
    describe("myDirective", function() {    
        var $compile;
        beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_){
            $compile = _$compile_;
            $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        }));
        it ("Should transform my text", function() {
            element = $compile('<my-directive text="test text" href="http://yahoo.com"></my-directive>')($rootScope);
            $rootScope.$digest();
            console.log(element.text());
        });
    });
});
```

The console.log(element.text()) in my test spits out an empty string... I can get it to read the attributes... i.e. If I add expect(element.attr('text')).toBe("test text") it will pass but that obviosuly doesn't test my actual directive and isn't what i want to do.

Comment: can you try `element.html()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rewriting your directive like so:

```
home.directive('myDirective', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            text: '@',
            link: '@'
        },
        template: '<p>Text: <a ng-href="{{link}}">{{text}}</a></p>',
        replace: true
    };
});
```

Then you can test like so:

```
describe( 'Test home controller', function() {
    beforeEach( module( 'home' ) );
    describe("myDirective", function() {    
        var $compile,
            $rootScope;
        beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_){
            $compile = _$compile_;
            $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        }));
        it ("Should transform my text", function() {
            element = $compile('<my-directive text="test text" link="http://yahoo.com"></my-directive>')($rootScope);
            $rootScope.$digest();
            console.log(element.text());
        });
    });
});
```

**Updated - Second Approach**

This updated approach demonstrates how you could use the link function along with `$observe`.

Try rewriting your directive like so:

```
home.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        template: '<p>Text: <a ng-href="{{link}}">{{text}}</a></p>',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs){
          attrs.$observe('text', function(newVal){
            scope.text = newVal + " tada";
          });
          attrs.$observe('link', function(newVal){
            scope.link = newVal + '/search?p=foo';
          });
        }
    };
});
```

Then you can test like so:

```
describe( 'Test home controller', function() {
    beforeEach( module( 'home' ) );
    describe("myDirective", function() {    
        var $compile;
        beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_){
            $compile = _$compile_;
            $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        }));
        it ("Should transform my text", function() {
            element = $compile('<my-directive text="test text" link="http://yahoo.com"></my-directive>')($rootScope);
            $rootScope.$digest();
            expect(element.text()).toBe('Text: test text tada');
        });
    });
});
```

[Here is a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MOuBFx?p=preview)

Comment: This works! But how would I test it using the link: function(scope, elem, attrs) { ... }. Lets assume I am doing some logic in there.

Comment: You can still have a link function, it just wasn't necessary in this scenario.

Comment: I will add some link manipulation in the link function to demonstrate for you.